# SEO: change site address from http://www. to https://

Tags: seo, google-search-console, google-search, https, no-www

My site was indexed as `http://www.example.com`.

**Purpose:** I would like to make a change to `https://example.com`

**Question:** Can you please give me a hint if I'm doing this in the best possible way?

**What I've done:**

1. I've made permanent redirection (301) from `http://www.example.com` and `http://example.com` to `https://example.com`
2. I've created 2 sitemaps:

   - `sitemap_w.xml` - which includes links like `http://www.example.com/some-page1/`, `http://www.example.com/some-page2/` etc. - I'm not sure if I should use https here too?
   - `sitemap_s.xml` - which includes links like `https://example.com/some-page1/`, `https://example.com/some-page2/` etc.

and included both of them in robots.txt

3. In Google Search Console I've added `https://www.example.com`  and `https://example.com`. For all of existing versions (`http://www` too) I've changed preferred domain to non-www.
4. In Google Search Console I've updated robots.txt and added both sitemaps:

   - for `http://www.example.com` I've `set sitemap_w.xml`
   - for `https://www.example.com` I've `set sitemap_s.xml`

This is all I've done. **Should I change something? Did I forget about any significant factor?**

Comment: You shouldn't have any redirecing URLs in your sitemap.  `sitemap_w.xml` is completely unneeded and probably harmful.

Comment: @StephenOstermiller what about this opinion? https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/webmasters/9uXVsQ18WQk/8MJ6wCTpFwAJ

Comment: Google doesn't need a sitemap to find the URLs in their old location -- it already knows about those.   Just make sure it can find the new ones.

Answer (score 1):

**When you migrate your site from http to HTTPS, then make sure, you do 301 redirection to all files even for XML sitemap.**

By giving two sitemaps, google just waste their crawling time, and it may cause some little delay to index your all webpages.

Comment: Thanks! What about this opinion https://productforums.google.com/forum/m/#!msg/webmasters/9uXVsQ18WQk/8MJ6wCTpFwAJ ? Is it totally wrong?

Comment: The answer given by Google employee, but as far I know, if you provide two sitemap, then Googlebot will crawl both URL's, and there are some limitation to crawling webpage, for example they don't crawl 5000 URL(p.s. Just a number) at a time, if you give them two sitemap to crawl, then it may not crawl all the webpages in same day, they will come back next day and start crawling remaining URL's. And Another thing is that Googlebot check sitemap only to discover new pages, if they see old url, then they may not crawl. Google often crawl old webpages from their index database.